# OffsetWidth error in Jq.carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I don't understand why I see this error.

> Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Code - http://jsfiddle.net/2EFsd/1/

```
var $carousel = $(' #carouse').carousel();

$('#carousel_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
  $carousel.carousel('prev');
});
$('#carousel_next').on('click', function(ev) {
  $carousel.carousel('next');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you type the selector correctly

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel').carousel();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2EFsd/2/)